# Passing different row id from appWidget to single instance of activity in task 

Tags: android, android-activity, task, android-appwidget

What I'd like to do is very similar to the "ColorNote" app. Basically I have app widgets that can launch "EditNote" activity and I want only one instance of the activity in the task; Say if user 1. taps widget A which launches "EditNote" A, 2. goes to home, 3. taps widget B which launches "EditNote" B, 4. then taps BACK button, user should land on home screen. I store the rowIds in an sqlite database and pass the row id of interest in the intent to get the "EditNote" activity.

I've tried to set the "launchMode" to either "singleTask" or "singleInstance", and Android would bypass "onCreate" and directly call "onNewIntent" (which is expected as it's documented), but the problem is each time the "EditNote" then gets the same intent which contains the same rowId, so step 3 above "EditNote" A would be launched instead. (If the "launchMode" is set to "standard", then the task would contain multiple "EditNote" activities with the correct ids.)

This is the code snippet in the appWidgetProvider:

```
int rowId = dataAccess.getIdByAppWidgetId(appWidgetId);
intent.putExtra(NoteColumns.ID, ((Integer)rowId).longValue());  
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, appWidgetId, 
                                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.appwidget, pending);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

Code in the "EditNote" activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "\\\\\\new intent: "
            +" the rowId is "+getIntent().getLongExtra(NoteColumns.ID, -1));
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
    }
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, in the above code, the EditNote.onNewIntent was never called. If I put this: intent.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(Uri.parse("ABCD" + "://widget/id/"), String.valueOf(appWidgetId))); the onNewIntent gets called but I would get a same row id each time (i.e., the first one passed in was redelivered each time). Hope I am missing something obvious here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out it's the key of the extra that went into the intent that caused the issue:

```
intent.putExtra(NoteColumnteger)rowId).longValue());
```

The "NoteColumns.ID" was "_id", the problem is gone when a slightly different key is used:

```
public static final String ROW_ID  = "rowId";
```

The puzzle remains unsolved as to why "_id" worked as expected when the activity's launchMode was "standard".

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do would be in Edit Note B, override onKeyDown and onKeyUp to start a new intent for the home screen as such:

```
     @Override
     public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
                 if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

         Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
         startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
         startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
         startActivity(startMain);
                    return true; //this tells android that you have handled the keypress
             }
             else return false; // this tells android to handle the key press

          return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
         }


        @Override
        public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){ // in new versions of android, to support canceled button presses on virtual keys, onKeyUp needs to be used
             super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event, mapview);
             if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

           Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
           startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
           startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
           startActivity(startMain);
                        return true; //this tells android that you have handled the keypress
                 }
                 else return false; // this tells android to handle the key press
             return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
            }
```

Comment: If the user presses BACK button to go to home screen, I've got it working the way I want without handling onKeyUp/Down. The problem comes from the user pressing HOME button directly and tapping on a new app widget. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, okay. Sorry. I misread. I was thinking your issue was with step 4. I re-read your explanation a little more thoroughly and now I understand. I'm trying to think up a solution.